# Space and absolute 0

Tags: space

If two objects like black holes or soild matter are separated by space, let's assume billions and billions of light years. While all other possible energy has left the area, and no new sources.  Like a universe in a heat death. If no more energy is possible does the space between the last energy have the ability to reach 0. If it hits 0 does this space exist ? Would the final objects with energy and billions and billions of years apart instantly appear that much closer?  Assuming the space between them hit 0 around the same time. Or is that type of thinking just way too far outside the box ?

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand what you are asking, but there is a scenario that is fairly close to what you seem to be having in mind. Yes, if space were to cool down so much that a phase transition were to occur that would re-scale a weakly interacting enormous cold universe into a strongly interacting small one. That's one of the possible "eternal inflation" models. Good thinking... even if you are not the first to come up with it.

Comment: yes it is too far ... even if it was possible, how could you rely this *theory of the sudden shrinking* to the other theories ? You cannot start from scratch with 3 sentences ( at least in physics :)

Comment: I had a long start before asking.